# How to mock mapping profile with mapping options

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, moq

I have a mapping profile that uses `IDictionary<string, object>` to pass a value. I's being used like this:

```
var viewModel = _mapper.Map<TransactionDetailsViewModel>(
    transaction,
    opt =>
    {
        opt.Items.Add( typeof(IClockService).Name, _systemClock );
    }
);
```

I've tried to mock it in a unit test, but always get `NotSupportedException` here:

```
Mock<IMapper> _mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
_mockMapper
    .Setup(
        mm => mm.Map<TransactionDetailsViewModel>(
            domainModel,
            opt => opt.Items.Add( typeof(IClockService).Name, _systemClock )
        )
    )
    .Returns( viewModel );
```

What is the correct way to mock such mapping method?

Here is the `StackTrace` :

```
 at Moq.MatcherFactory.CreateMatcher(Expression expression)
   at Moq.MatcherFactory.CreateMatcher(Expression argument, ParameterInfo parameter)
   at Moq.MatcherFactory.CreateMatchers(IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, ParameterInfo[] parameters)
   at Moq.InvocationShape..ctor(LambdaExpression expression, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, Boolean exactGenericTypeArguments)
   at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.<Split>g__Split|4_1(Expression e, Expression& r, InvocationShape& p)
   at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression)
   at Moq.Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression)
   at Hosts.Api.Tests.TransactionsControllerTests.GetTransaction_WhenAdvance_ConvertsSpread() in C:\Users\RS\source\repos\Project\src\UnitTests\Hosts.Api.Tests\Operations\Transactions\TransactionsControllerTests.cs:line 211
```

Message:

```
Unsupported expression: opt => 
opt.Items.Add(Services.ClockService.Interfaces.IClockService.Name,
value(Hosts.Api.Tests.TransactionsControllerTests)._systemClock)
```

Comment: I suggest that you shouldn't mock `IMapper`: it should behave the same in all circumstances: (unit-test, integration-test, and normal running) - and AutoMapper supports DI anyway. Is there a reason you want to mock it in your tests? (You can always _configure_ AutoMapper differently for test use, but that's not the same thing as Mocking it).

Comment: @Dai I agree that the better option would be just to inject real version of mapper in the tested service. In the current unit test, as well as other, in the class the mapper was mocked. I didn't want to update all of the unit test after changing implementation of the tested service and adding small change to the mapping profile. Just wandering what exactly is incorrect in the way I tried to mock options. The version without options worked as expected.

Comment: Where is the `NotSupportedException` being thrown from, exactly? (i.e. what's the top lines of the `StackTrace`?) How does `domainModel` comapre to `transaction`?

Comment: btw, consider using `nameof(IClockService)` instead of `typeof(IClockService).Name` (`nameof()` doesn't work for generic type arguments, ofc).

Comment: Thank you. I will. Here is the StackTrace: 
 `at Moq.MatcherFactory.CreateMatcher(Expression expression) `
   `at Moq.MatcherFactory.CreateMatcher(Expression argument, ParameterInfo ` `parameter)`
   `at Moq.MatcherFactory.CreateMatchers(IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, `ParameterInfo[] parameters)
   at Moq.InvocationShape..ctor(LambdaExpression expression, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, Boolean exactGenericTypeArguments)
   at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.<Split>g__Split|4_1(Expression e, Expression& r, InvocationShape& p)  ...

Comment: Please post the stack-trace in your original question, not in a comment reply (because it's truncated, so we can't see the full trace).

Comment: Thank you for posting the full stack-trace, however we also need all details from the `NotSupportedException`, what is the `.Message` property value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I don't mock the mapper; I think most of the time integration testing the mapping profiles is a good thing however I do do it from time to time as the need requires.

Start with specifying a matcher for the options:

```
mapperMock.Setup(x => x.Map<TransactionDetailsViewModel>(
        transaction,
        It.Is<Action<IMappingOperationOptions>>(opt => AddsItem(opt, nameof(IClockService), systemClock)))).Returns(viewModel);
```

You can't match on the delegate itself, but in this case you can match on what it's doing - adding an item to the items dictionary. I've delegated the actual comparison to the method `AddsItem` to keep the code readable.

```
public bool AddsItem(Action<IMappingOperationOptions> providedOptions, string key, object value)
{
    var mappingOptions = new CustomMappingOperationOptions();
    providedOptions.Invoke(mappingOptions);
    return mappingOptions.Items.Any(x => x.Key.Equals(key) && x.Value.Equals(value));
}
```

Basically the comparison resolves what the delegate was doing and returns true or false depending on whether it did what we expected. Chop and change the comparison to suit, I'm making assumptions here. `CustomMappingOperationOptions` is just a quick local implementation of `IMappingOperationOptions` as the concrete implementation looked like a bit of a pain and we don't need it for the test.

Finally, pull it all together:

```
var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
mapperMock.Setup(x => x.Map<TransactionDetailsViewModel>(
        transaction,
        It.Is<Action<IMappingOperationOptions>>(opt => AddsItem(opt, nameof(IClockService), new ClockService())))).Returns(viewModel);

var mockedMapper = mapperMock.Object;

var result = mockedMapper.Map<TransactionDetailsViewModel>(transaction, opt => opt.Items.Add(nameof(IClockService), new ClockService()));
```

Comment: Thank you rgvlee. I still ended up using real mapping profile, but this solution what I was looking for and it worked. I tried mocking `IMappingOperationOptions`  inside  `Additems()` like this:

       `public bool AddItems(Action<IMappingOperationOptions> opt, string key, object value)
        {
            var mapOptions = new Mock<IMappingOperationOptions>();
            mapOptions.Setup(x => x.Items).Returns(new StringDictionary());
            opt.Invoke(mapOptions.Object);
            return mapOptions.Object.Items.Any(x => x.Key.Equals(key) && x.Value.Equals(value));
        }`

Comment: Hi Roman, nice work, the Returns with a new dictionary works well in this case.